# How to use xpath referance name in JDBC Request SQL Query?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, sql

How to use xpath reference name in JDBC request?below configuration i have tested but its not  working. Is there any way to get this xml value[prodcutid] in to SQL Query?

**Jmeter DB Request**

[image]

**XPATH Extractor**

[image]

**XML**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your `id` column type you can do it in 2 ways:

1. If `id` is **VARCHAR** type you will need to surround `${Productid}` reference with quotation marks like:

   ```
   `SELECT * FROM prodcut WHERE id = '${productid}'
   ```
2. If `id` is **INTEGER** type you will need to switch to `Prepared Select Statement` like:

   [image: JMeter JDBC]

Also according to [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions)

> Variables, functions (and properties) are all case-sensitive

so `${productid}` and `${Productid}` are **different variables** so please make sure that definition and all references are in line.

See [Building a Database Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) and [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) articles for more information on implementing database testing using JMeter.

Comment: If id is BIGINT in prepared select statement, error message given  --> For input string: "${productid}". how to fix this? https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27605/jmeter-jdbc-request-parameter-type-bigint